# How do you install a Topshelf service in a remote machine?

Tags: topshelf

To install a Topshelf service, I normally simply do:

```
myservice.exe install
```

If I want to install the service on a remote machine, I can't just do:

```
\\server\c$\myservice.exe install
```

...because it would still install the service on my local machine.

How can I install a Topshelf service on a remote machine without having to log onto that machine and run the executable directly from there?

Comment: Try looking into Octopus Deploy which does just that ...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides a tool called [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx). It has a whole bunch of feature one of which is to run command on remote machines.

Edit:

File Deployment: To get the files to the target machine you would have to do some sort of copy, whether that be manually or with some sort of script.

Install: Install psexec on your machine, it may need to be installed on the remote machine but I do not remember. Open command prompt on your machine, type

```
psexec \\remotecomputername -u admin@domain.com -p p@$$w0rd "c:\applications\myprogram\myprogram.bat"
```

In this case remotecomputername is the name of the computer your are targeting. If you need to login as another user, use the -u and -p switches in the example and finally, put the path to the exe "c:\applications..."

Comment: OK, but that's too vague to answer the question - at least an example would be nice.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I wish there were a way to do this using Topshelf itself or native Windows tools, but this method is good enough.